# Curved and square brackets in a function

Tags: functions

How does the function $df({\bf{a}})[X]$ read and what are the roles of the square brackets versus the curved brackets? For ${\bf{a}},X \in \mathbb{R^{3}}$. d being the total derivative.

Comment: Many authors use the two interchangeably. It makes text easier to read.

Comment: Looks like here you're evaluating the total derivative at a point $a$ on a tangent vector $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on RghtHndSd's comments, When $f$ is a map from a domain $U \subseteq \Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$, then the derivative of $f$ *at a given point $\mathbf a$ in its domain* is a linear map between the *vector spaces* $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$. That, $df(\mathbf a)$ is not just a value. It is function itself. So if we want to evaluate this map for a vector $X \in \Bbb R^m$, we would write it as $$df(\mathbf a)(X)$$
But the paired parentheses is odd-looking, and perhaps a little confusing. So your book has chosen to use square brackets for the second set. Common alternative notations include $df|_{\mathbf a}(X)$ or just $df_{\mathbf a}(X)$.

Why not write it as $df(\mathbf a, X)$? Especially since both $\mathbf a, X \in \Bbb R^m$? This is because the author wants to distinguish between the roles of $\mathbf a$ and $X$, which are quite different. You really don't even want to think of them as both coming from the same space. $\mathbf a$ is an element of $U$. Here $U$ is just an open subset of $\Bbb R^m$, but the concept is generalizable to cases where this isn't true. For example, we could have $U = S^2$, the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$. This isn't an open set in $\Bbb R^3$, but we can differentiate in directions along the sphere. The vectors $X$ then are vectors in the plane tangent to the sphere at $\mathbf a$. This situation is quite common, and there is an entire field of mathematics devoted to it, Differential Geometry.

Whatever the space $U$ or the notation used, $df(\mathbf a)[X]$ is the derivative of $f$ at $\mathbf a$ in the direction of $X$.

Comment: By convention if $T$ is linear one writes $Tx$ for $T(x)$. So here, assuming that the notation means what we both think it means, I'd tend to write $df(a)X$.